# Как удалить программу в Ubuntu 20 (sphinx) если не знаешь куда её установил?

Tags: ubuntu, sphinx

Как удалить программу в Ubuntu 20 (sphinx) если не знаешь куда её установил?

Устанавливал Sphinx из исходников:

- установил необходимые пакеты для сборки Sphinx:
  sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libc6-dev libc6 make gcc g++
- sudo -i
- cd /tmp
- wget http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.1.7-release.tar.gz -O sphinx.tar.gz
- tar -zxvf sphinx.tar.gz
- sudo ./configure --with-pgsql
- sudo make && sudo make install

Sphinx установился. searchd --help вижу версию 2.1.7-release

Но это не то, чего я ожидал. Как удалить?
очень неуверенный пользователь Linux.

Comment: Не знаю, как оно отработает, но по крайней мере `make uninstall` в этом архиве вроде бы есть. Ну а в целом использовать `make install` не надо вообще никогда

Comment: А в линуксе и не надо знать, куда устанавливаются программы. Это знание все равно вам ничем не поможет. Да и незачем было устанавливать из исходников, к тому же старую версию, ведь там рядом лежат готовые установочные файлы.